# How to set the origin of a cube to its apex in blender?

Tags: blender

For a cube with location (0, 0, 0) I wont it's apex to be at the origin of the coordinate system.

(apex = left bottom front point of the cube)

I tried Tools > Edit > Set Origin.

But it's not possible to achieve what I described.

So how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is blender 2.8+, then:

1. Press `TAB`, then select vertex you want to be an origin point.
2. `SHIFT  + S`, then `Cursor to Selected`.
3. Again `TAB`, `Right mouse click`, then `Origin to 3D Cursor`

If not:

1. Press `TAB`, then select vertex you want to be an origin point.
2. `SHIFT + S`, then `Cursor to Selected`.
3. Again `TAB`, then `SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+C`, then `Origin to 3D Cursor`